# 2 legend objects with arcgis javascript api

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

Can i create 2 legend objects in one script?

I'm currently working on a web-application in which i already do have a legend/TOC running and it looks like this:

```
var legendLayers=[];
    legendLayers.push({layer:raum, title:'Raumkategorien', slider:true});
        map.on("layers-add-result", function(){
        var layerInfo = new TOC({
                map: map,
                layerInfos: legendLayers,
        }, "legendDiv");
        layerInfo.startup();
    });
    map.addLayers([raum]);
```

Now I added some geoprocessing functionality and i wanted to add a new TOC when the result map is loaded in the web-app.
I tried this by doing the following:

```
function gpJobComplete(jobinfo){
        var mapurl = mapServiceURL + "/" + jobinfo.jobId;
        var energy = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(mapurl,{
            id:"Beste Energieformen",
            "opacity": 0.85
        });
        map.addLayers([energy]);

        var outputLayers = [];
        outputLayers.push({layer:energy, title:"Beste Energieformen"});
        map.on("layers-add-result", function(){
            domUtils.show(dom.byId('outputDiv'));
            var outputInfo = new TOC({
                map: map,
                layerInfos: outputLayers
            }, "outputDiv");
        outputInfo.startup();
        });
    }
```

I get a result map and it works just nice in the web app, but there's no new TOC.
Am i trying it the wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you destroyed your previous TOC?  I've found that the legend widget get's confused if you build a new one without first destroying the old one.  The legend widget has a destroy method, I'm not sure if the TOC does as well.  Try completely removing the old TOC before building a new one.

Good Luck.

It's essentially something like this.  But as I said I'm just using the legend widget not the TOC widget.

```
        if (biosatApp.hasOwnProperty("legend")) {
            biosatApp.legend.destroy();
            domConstruct.destroy(dojo.byId("legendDiv"));
        }
        // create a new div for the legend
        var legendDiv = domConstruct.create("div", {
            id: "legendDiv"
        }, dom.byId("EILegendContainer"));

        biosatApp.legend = new Legend({
            map: biosatApp.map,
            layerInfos: biosatApp.legendLayers
        }, legendDiv);
        biosatApp.legend.startup();
```

Comment: @Simmal try destroying the TOC.  I think layerInfos is the list of legend layers, but not the actual legend.

Comment: No, i destroyed layerInfo not layerInfos and layerInfo was the TOC (var layerInfo = new TOC). See the first script. I saw that you had some similar problem. Is it possible that i can have a look on your script and how it worked?

Comment: I just realised that the TOC won't show after running the geoprocessing task even though i uncommented the first (existing) TOC.

Comment: If you did a destroy it may have obliterated the entire div that it was in.  You have to recreate the div to create a new legend/TOC in it.  If you notice in the code above I have to create a div for the legend after destroying it.

Comment: Thanks. That obviously worked. I just had the problem that i defined my variable for the existing TOC in another funstion. I think that might have been the problem so that the second function didn't know about that variable.

Comment: just realised that i just created a new div and that the legend also loads the previous version. it's not just a problem of the TOC widget. if i use the legend wiedget and call legend.destroy() it doesn't work, too.

Answer (score 0):

so i tried destroying the existing toc and creating a new one like this, but it doesn't seem to work

```
function gpJobComplete(jobinfo){
        var mapurl = mapServiceURL + "/" + jobinfo.jobId;
        var energy = new ArcGISDynamicMapServiceLayer(mapurl,{
            id:"Beste Energieformen",
            "opacity": 0.85
        });

        layerInfo.destroy();
        var outputLayers = [];
        outputLayers.push({layer:energy, title:"Beste Energieformen"});
        map.on("layers-add-result", function(){
            var outputInfo = new TOC({
                map: map,
                layerInfos: outputLayers
            }, "outputDiv");
        outputInfo.startup();
        });
        map.addLayers([energy]);
    }
```